# Greasemonkey GM_listValues fails, workaround cloneInto fails in Firefox 36

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

In current Version of Greasemonkey 2.3 the function GM_listValues is broken, it returns an empty undefined.

Found this workaround https://greasyfork.org/de/forum/discussion/2918/issue-with-gm-getvalue-from-gm-listvalues-array-in-firefox

```
var list = cloneInto(GM_listValues(), window);
```

It worked in Firefox 35.01. Now, in FF 36 i get a new JS error:

```
Permission denied to pass object to privileged code
```

Has anybody any idea how I can still use current Greasemonkey, current Firefox and the method GM_listValues() ?

Comment: This is a bug in Greasemonkey scheduled to be fixed with GM 2.4.  Hand apply the patches to your local copy of GM if you can't wait.